# Show partial using ui.bootstrap collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row of buttons in my Angular.js application that currently open up a new route, showing a new partial view on the page. My new task is to make some of those buttons trigger a ui.bootstrap Collapse with the view inside of it. The markup from ui.bootstrap examples is:

```
<div ng-controller="CollapseDemoCtrl">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Toggle collapse</button>
    <hr>
    <div uib-collapse="isCollapsed">
        <div class="well well-lg">Some content</div>
    </div>
</div>

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('CollapseDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.isCollapsed = false;
});
```

What i would like is to show one of my partials where "Some content" is inside of the markup above. Thus, I would have buttons like this:

Parties  |   Future Events

When I click on Parties it currently loads the parties by going to a path /parties/:number where :number is the case number to look at.

What I want to change this to is the same buttons, but when i click Parties it slides open a DIV that contains the parties. One challenge I have is that the parties are retrieved via a separate web service and I am not sure how I can build my page to have those hidden away somewhere. Is it possible to load them when requested?

How do I accomplish this task? Ultimately I will need to use multiple collapse statements triggering from my various buttons. This is because I have multiple rows of data on this page. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may inject your partial inside the collapse panel. It's quite easy and manageable such approach. The controller will take care which and when a partial will be loaded.

Take a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gk1oFC2iawv7K1PeBggc?p=preview).

In the example above I have used a simple getter function to grab the partial and load it inside my panel as:

```
<div uib-collapse="Main.isCollapsed">
    <div class="well well-lg">
        <div ng-include="Main.getPartialUrl()"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this looks exactly like what I need with one exception. My partial currently loads the data via a value in the route (case number is passed to it). How can I do that in this method?

Comment: 1) Grab the ID from the state and load the partial.
2) Watrch for any ID changes to keep the partial up to date.

Comment: OK, this almost works, but the problem is that I have multiple rows, each that needs to have a div show or hide when a button is clicked. Right now when I click ANY "Parties" button ALL Parties divs show. How can I do something similar to what I would do with JQuery--add an ID to each DIV and have the function call know what ID was supposed to open and only open THAT div?

Comment: Nope, jQuery is event driven. You should map the changes to your controller and handle this issue using `ng-show`

Comment: I wasn't saying I would use JQuery, I was asking how I would do something similar in angular. Somehow I need to know which doc will open and all others should close. What about angular.element?

Comment: Don't use events or DOM queries, append models on the elements. That should do the trick.
Take a look over here http://jsfiddle.net/angularjs_de/6VErN/

Comment: Thanks for the Fiddle, but it still only shows how to handle this with ONE div being toggled. I have created a JSFiddle that exemplifies how I would accomplish this in JQuery (I KNOW not to use JQuery to do this with Angular) and I would like to know how to accomplish this same thing in Angular. http://jsfiddle.net/mikemahony/avjgb67o/